# Rancher desktop Error: wsl.exe exited with code 4294967295

Tags: docker, windows-10-universal, rancher-desktop

I am trying to run rancher desktop version 1.10 (I have also tried the older versions of rancher desktop 1.7, 1.8, 1.9) at the time of installing it in my windows 10 system it is giving me the below error. please Check SS.

[image]

I have tried to update WSL and other steps to resolve it but not get success.
When I tried to install WSL through CMD, It gives me below error...

```
system32> wsl --install -d Ubuntu
Installing: Ubuntu
Ubuntu has been installed.
Catastrophic failure
Error code: Wsl/InstallDistro/E_UNEXPECTED
```

Could anyone please help me with this issue? It's been 3 weeks now.

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried to update WSL.

```
wsl --update
```

Reinstall rancher desktop.

Checked the below settings in turn on & off windows feature.
windows subsystem for Linux
virtual machine

Restart PC multiple times

Upgrade the windows software